# protect gas lines from corrosion?

Tags: fuel-system, corrosion, underbody

'07 Cobalt, electric power steering, 50K miles

Snow/slush/salt area.  The car (new to us) hasn't had a lot of winter miles, so it's in not-too-bad condition.  However, underneath today, I saw that the gas lines are showing corrosion in the usual places, near the (plastic) mounting brackets. In time, leaks will develop and I'll have to splice the lines.

Question: can I do anything now to prevent further deterioration?  I imagine the factory finish is better than anything I could do with paint, etc., but maybe some sort of goo -  DIY undercoat, rubber spray or roofing cement? Have people had success with anything?

Comment: Have you looked at POR-15 before?

Comment: Are you sure those gas lines are regular steel?  I'd strongly suspect they are made of plastic with segments of stainless steel. Question. Have you personally tried a magnet on the fuel lines at your alleged rust areas?  That is a quick and easy test.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2: I hadn't heard of POR-15.  It looks kind of magical.  Have you ever used it?  Over rust?

Comment: Yes. It is fairly magical ... not really. The only real downfall to it is it cannot stand up to direct sunlight. If it requires it to be out in the light, cover it with something else (ie: paint). It works like they say on their website. Use throw away brushes to apply as once it's on something, it won't come off. Also, clean the part as best you can, but it doesn't have to be perfect. Also, it will bond metal together. Be cognizant of this.